# How do i align colorbox with my text?

Tags: colorbox

I am trying to insert colored boxes into my caption like below.

[image]

But my code below does not align the colored boxes with the text. How can I automatically align them with the text?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}

\title{test}
\author{test}%

\date{January 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{figure}
$A^{L}$ \includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth,height=0.25cm]{example-image-a} $A^{R}$ \includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth,height=0.25cm]{example-image-a}\\
$\hat{A}^{L}$ \includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth,height=0.25cm]{example-image-a} $\hat{A}^{R}$ \includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth,height=0.25cm]{example-image-a}\\
$\hat{A}^{L}$ \includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth,height=0.25cm]{example-image-a} $\hat{A}^{R}$ \includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth,height=0.25cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Qualitative results for recognition. Stir \colorbox{red!80}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE contain error: syntax for `\collorbox` is `\colorbox{<color>}{<content>}`. Instead of use a `\colorbox` is define new command as is better to define new command as is done in @Simon Dispa answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try this code. It was added a command `\Cbox{<color>}` that puts a framed colored square on the baseline.

[image: d]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}

\title{test}
\author{test}%

\date{January 2022}

\newcommand{\Cbox}[1]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fbox{\color{#1}\rule{2ex}{2ex}}} % added <<<<<<<<<<<
    
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    $A^{L}$ \includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth,height=0.25cm]{example-image-a} $A^{R}$ \includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth,height=0.25cm]{example-image-a}\\
    $\hat{A}^{L}$ \includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth,height=0.25cm]{example-image-a} $\hat{A}^{R}$ \includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth,height=0.25cm]{example-image-a}\\
    $\hat{A}^{L}$ \includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth,height=0.25cm]{example-image-a} $\hat{A}^{R}$ \includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth,height=0.25cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Qualitative results for recognition: \Cbox{red!80}~stir, \Cbox{green}~lift,  \Cbox{gray!50}~idle,  \Cbox{yellow}~hold, \Cbox{blue!30}~approach.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```